# Linear trans on normal distribution

Tags: statistical-significance, data-transformation, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics

Let's say a variable fits a ratio measurement level and is also normally distributed (for example, height). Why is it possible to do a linear transformation on such a variable if the only transformation which is allowed on ratio measurements is multiplication or division?

Comment: By "linear" do you mean y = ax or y = ax + b?

Comment: The short answer is that there isn't anything that corresponds to your irreconcilable assumptions: the question is vacuous.

Answer (score 1):

1. A variable won't be both ratio and exactly normal (at least not for strictly non-negative variables like height).
2. Leaving aside the issue of normality:

   Lets say I have a ratio variable like $X_i$ = "number of hours worked on day $i$", and the corresponding daily pay is "\$10 + \$30 per hour" (perhaps the ten dollars is some meal allowance or travel allowance or something, it's not important). Then the daily pay amount *is* a linear transformation of the hours worked and Stevens' "rule" about transformation of a ratio variable in that situation is plainly no help to us - a linear transformation is not only possible in that situation, it's *inherent* in the definition of the pay amount variable.

You might find my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/106400/805) on issues with Stevens' typology of scale of some interest.